# Error in migrating OWL data into GRAKN

Tags: vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

I am trying to migrate a `OWL` data into `GRAKN` using the migration script as described [here](https://grakn.ai/pages/documentation/examples/OWL-migration.html). I started my `GRAKN` engine and then executed `./migration.sh owl -i /home/file1.owl -k grakn` but I get this error:

```
Migrating data /home/file1.owl using Grakn Engine localhost:4567 into graph grakn
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Graph Factory [ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory] is not valid
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.newFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:101)
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.getGraknGraphFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:82)
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.getFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:62)
    at ai.grakn.factory.GraknSessionImpl.configureGraphFactoryRemote(GraknSessionImpl.java:153)
    at ai.grakn.factory.GraknSessionImpl.configureGraphFactory(GraknSessionImpl.java:134)
    at ai.grakn.factory.GraknSessionImpl.getConfiguredFactory(GraknSessionImpl.java:90)
    at ai.grakn.factory.GraknSessionImpl.open(GraknSessionImpl.java:79)
    at ai.grakn.migration.owl.Main.runOwl(Main.java:64)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4717)
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4725)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at ai.grakn.migration.owl.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.newFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:99)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1325)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
    at ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory.configureGraph(TitanInternalFactory.java:113)
    at ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory.newTitanGraph(TitanInternalFactory.java:88)
    at ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory.buildTinkerPopGraph(TitanInternalFactory.java:84)
    at ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory.buildTinkerPopGraph(TitanInternalFactory.java:60)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.getTinkerPopGraph(AbstractInternalFactory.java:141)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.getTinkerPopGraph(AbstractInternalFactory.java:135)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.getGraph(AbstractInternalFactory.java:110)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.open(AbstractInternalFactory.java:95)
    at ai.grakn.factory.SystemKeyspace.loadSystemOntology(SystemKeyspace.java:114)
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.newFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:107)
    at ai.grakn.factory.FactoryBuilder.getGraknGraphFactory(FactoryBuilder.java:82)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.getSystemFactory(AbstractInternalFactory.java:80)
    at ai.grakn.factory.AbstractInternalFactory.<init>(AbstractInternalFactory.java:74)
    at ai.grakn.factory.TitanInternalFactory.<init>(TitanInternalFactory.java:64)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:580)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:291)
    ... 49 more
```

Is there any mistake in the command I am executing to do the migration? What can I do to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:** I was able to resolve the above issue but now I am getting following error in trying to start the `graql shell`:

```
Exception in thread "graql-session-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1437)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)
    at ai.grakn.graph.internal.AbstractGraknGraph.loadOntologyCacheIntoTransactionCache(AbstractGraknGraph.java:337)
    at ai.grakn.graph.internal.AbstractGraknGraph.getConceptLog(AbstractGraknGraph.java:307)
    at ai.grakn.graph.internal.AbstractGraknGraph.buildType(AbstractGraknGraph.java:450)
    at ai.grakn.graph.internal.AbstractGraknGraph.getTypeByLabel(AbstractGraknGraph.java:548)
    at ai.grakn.graph.internal.AbstractGraknGraph.getMetaConcept(AbstractGraknGraph.java:608)
    at ai.grakn.engine.session.GraqlSession.getTypes(GraqlSession.java:371)
    at ai.grakn.engine.session.GraqlSession.sendTypes(GraqlSession.java:348)
    at ai.grakn.engine.session.GraqlSession.lambda$new$48(GraqlSession.java:105)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What version of Grakn are you using? Also can you confirm that engine and cassandra are running with `./grakn.sh status`

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I backtraced the problem through error logs to the issue with Cassandra and it wasn't starting due to some permission issue on one of the files. I `sudo` restarted the `grakn` engine and then executed the migration script again and can see `Migration Complete` getting printed on the console. But the command prompts does not return back after `Migration complete` is printed. And how do i verify if migration is complete as I do not see any grakn graph file getting generated at the location where the `OWL` file is present?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I am using `0.12.1` version

Comment: The grakn graph is actually persisted inside cassandra which is located in `GRAKN_HOME/db/cassandra`. To confirm it has loaded you can log into the graql shell with `./graql -k grakn ` and the run the query `match $x sub entity` and this should show some information, specifically your data.

With regards to the terminal stalling on `Migration Complete` this is a known issue with `0.12.1` which has already been fixed and should be release shortly. 

By the way you should add your discovery as an answer it might be useful to others.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira  is the command `./graql -k grakn` or `./graql.sh -k grakn`? I ran `./graql.sh -k grakn` and it does not open any shell but just shows logging initialized and the prompt does not return back. Also I ran `match $x sub entity` from the web dashboard and it shows a bunch of entities on a graph with numbers like `tN0000...` but I don't know if its the data I just migrated or some sample example data already loaded.

Comment: Doing via the web dashboard will net the same result. If you seeing that information then that means migration was completed and your owl file was loaded. 

The command is `./graql.sh -k grakn`. Odd that is not accessing the shell. What environment are you running on?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I restarted my grakn enigne and now even the web interface is throwing `exception:null` on the query

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Also when I executed `match $x isa resource` I saw names like `Ron`, `Samuel` which when I checked in my owl file are not there. Are there some sample data also present which might show up on the graph?

Comment: That is only possible if you used the graph in some way before hand. `grakn` is the default keyspace so when you operate on the graph and don't provide a keyspace it defaults to that one.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira How can I print(maybe like a subset) the resulting Graql statements after migration from OWL?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I have pasted the traceback when I try to launch the graql shell in my post above.